# Insert a record in table fails everytime

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a database connection where i insert data into the table having 2 columns i.e. `id`,`first_name`,`last_name`.
Following is the code:

```
    private void Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            String query = "INSERT INTO  data_table (first_name,last_name) VALUES (@f_name,@l_name)";

            using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(
                                      Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnection))

            using (SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection1))
            {
                //a shorter syntax to adding parameters
              //  insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@f_name", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = "JAVED";

                insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@l_name", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = "GHAMJN";

                //make sure you open and close(after executing) the connection
                connection1.Open();
                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection1.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Record inserted. Please check your table data. :)");

            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);

        }
  }
```

Following is T-SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[data_table] (
[Id]         INT        NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[first_name] NCHAR (10) NULL,
[last_name]  NCHAR (10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
 );
```

The issue is created by id: I have set it auto-increment.
When i click insert button a MessageBox pops saying:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id',table 'C:\Users.......\Database1.MDF.dbo.data_table;column doesn't allows null.INSERT fails

Comment: try create table with `with [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)`

Comment: STILL the same issue :-(

Comment: You're looking at the wrong database or table.

Comment: Make sure you have only 1 copy of the database and that the referenced database is the one that you made the changes to. VS tries to be smart and ask about copying the mdf to your local folder.

Comment: Agree with others your connectionstring point elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Id field should be modified as shown below

[image]

Comment: This should work, try with Id allows null see if it works to detect that problem is not else where

Comment: those fields names are different

Comment: Restarting the same Project and adding a new table named `Table_New  `after deleting that one gives me: invalid Object `Table_New  `

Comment: On each new start of VS i don't find my table in Server Object explorer

Comment: "I don't find my table in Server Object explorer" Are you connecting to the database in `bin/Debug` instead of the one in your `App_Data` or project root?

Answer (score 1):

Add identity seed and increment values to your table...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[data_table] (
[Id]         INT        NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
[first_name] NCHAR (10) NULL,
[last_name]  NCHAR (10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
 );
```

Comment: STILL the same issue :-(

Comment: If you right click on you table Script Table as - > Create to -> New Query Editor Window - is the seed there now? Also if using Table adapters try and refresh your table adapters...

Comment: Does it needs table deletion/re-creation?

Comment: The seed and increment values are not required, see here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms188059.aspx). The behaviour of Identity Columns can be selectively enabled or disabled with this statement.

If your Identity Column is configured correctly, then this is the only logical explanation for it not behaving as expected

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[data_table] ON;

---

However, it is more likely that your assertion of correctness is flawed and you have not configured the Identity Column correctly.

Comment: Where should i try it?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting that table alongwith all the old copies of old table  and creating a new table with suggested `Identity(1,1)` resolved the issue

Comment: This is not answer, unfortunately. The seed values are not necessary for the `IDENTITY` property, see here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx This indicates that there was some unknown problem with your previous table object.

Comment: YES a Restart of VS was sufficient for problem removal..Actually a messagebox was not allowing VS to be closed and a non-premptive effort did it